# Android : Calendar Event added in different date

Tags: android, android-calendar

I tried to add an event in a default mobile calendar from android application

```
private void setEvent(){        
        long startMilis = 0;
        int mCalId = 1;
        long endMilis = 0;
        Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        beginTime.set(2013, 8, 16, 9, 10);
        startMilis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();  
        Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        endTime.set(2013,8, 18, 10,10);
        endMilis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, mCalId);
        values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMilis);
        values.put(Events.DTEND, endMilis);
        values.put(Events.TITLE,"Our Event");
        values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group Activity");
        values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "Morocco");
        Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Event Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

The event is added , but in different date  , it is added in 16 Septembre 2013 to 18 Septembre 
PS : the date in mobile is true ( no configuration problem )